# How can I install HDF4 on Mac and use it for GDAL?

Tags: homebrew, gdal, hdf

I would like to convert a series of HDF4-files via GDAL, but it needs the possibility to read this format (HDF4). This can probably be done by installing the package hdf4. The easiest way possible would be:

```
brew install hdf4
```

But that results in

```
No available formula with the name "hdf4".
```

Can anyone help me out? All articles I found on the internet originate from ~2015 and do not solve my problem (anymore).

Comment: Using `conda` (miniconda) in combination with the `gdal` from the `conda-forge` channel should come with hdf4 support. I can't test it on Mac, but it's the case on Windows.

Comment: I couldn't solve this with brew yet, but Google Collab has gdal with hdf4 installed as a base package. Maybe as an interim solution.